# DatePicker from AngularJS is storing date time with the timezone;

Tags: javascript, angularjs, postgresql, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I am using AngularJS datepicker that comes with.

I have a start date and end date , i.e. two control, with time picker.

I have a problem in understanding on when I am selecting 5:00, it is saved as 7:00 however on UI I can see it is displaying only 5.

How can assure that the timezone settings are not stored in the database.
And why there is a difference of 2 hours in selecting and saving, as shown this is screen shots.

UI angularjs controls.

[image]

Database Entry:

[image]

Please note: I am on GMT+10 timezone

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I was just doing battle with this for hours two days ago, but for a slightly different problem. The fundamental issue is that the datetime picker is using the JavaScript Date object, which uses your local time-zone information. That's the explanation for *why* this is happening.

As for your question, how can you be sure that it doesn't store the time zone information in your database, that's very hard to answer without knowing what your database is, your middileware, etc it's hard to answer. However, the solution will probably be to stringify the Date and adjust it for your the client's local timezone.

Comment: thanks for commenting I am also pulling my hairs for last couple of hours, however, if I am stringify then there is so much spagety code here and there...  I have added this; however then angular does not recognise the same. I am using nodejs with postgres.

Comment: I would recommend stringifying only in your $http.post. That way you don't have to keep changing it here and there. You can use the date filter, if you want to change the way a Date object is printed.